# If element is not present in NightwatchJS how to stop test without error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nightwatch.js, e2e-testing

In my Nightwatch test I have a before each that runs and removes an app from Facebook. If the app isn't present I just want to stop the before test.

```
.waitForElementPresent('#root div.touchable a', 2000, false, function (result) {
  if (result.value === false) {
    browser.saveScreenshot('./test/e2e/img/element-not-there.png')
    browser.end()
  }
})
.doSomethingIfElementIsThere() // not real ;)
```

This doesn't seem to work even with setting the `false` parameter. I get this error:

```
ERROR: Unable to locate element: "#root div.touchable a" using: css selector
    at Object.before (/Users/user/projects/project/test/e2e/specs/testy-mc-test-face.js:30:8)
 ✖ Timed out while waiting for element <#root div.touchable a> to be present for 2500 milliseconds.  - expected "found" but got: "not found"
    at Object.before (/Users/user/projects/project/test/e2e/specs/testy-mc-test-face.js:30:8)
```

Just wondered how it's possible to check something and not error. Or carry on with the assertions if the element is present?

Merci buckets

Comment: isn't the fact that the element is missing a failure condition for the test?  It really should be the job of the code you are testing to handle this gracefully so the test can interact with it either way, not the test's responsibility to selectively not run the test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I checked the [code of the `elementPresent` assertion](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/blob/master/lib/api/assertions/elementPresent.js):

```
this.command = function(callback) {
  return this.api.elements(this.client.locateStrategy, selector, callback);
};

this.value = function(result) {
  return (result.status !== 0 || result.value.length === 0) ? 'not present' : 'present';
};
```

It uses a [low-level api](http://nightwatchjs.org/api#elements) that you can use to test if an element is present:

> .elements()
>
> Search for multiple elements on the page, starting from the document root. The located elements will be returned as WebElement JSON objects.
>   First argument to be passed is the locator strategy, which is detailed on the WebDriver docs.

I suppose the solution can look like this:

```
browser.elements('css selector', '#root div.touchable a', result => {
  const isPresent = result.status === 0 && result.value.length > 0;
  // doStuff
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this, work's like a charm. Made me realise that I should jump in to the source code more. Thanks again

Comment: I suppose you can validate my answer :-)